# High non-mapped virtual memory for mongodb

Tags: mongodb, memory-management

I am seeing some very high non-mapped virtual memory usage for MongoDB. I can see the large amount of virtual memory in `top` and `pmap` tells me most of it is not allocated to files. Furthermore `MMS` confirms this by showing a large amount of non-mapped virtual memory.

The `MMS` description of the graph states the following about non-mapped virtual memory:

> If this number is very high (multiple gigabytes), it indicates that excessive memory is being used by other aspects than the memory mapping of files -- that would be bad/suboptimal. The most common case of usage of a high amount of memory for non-mapped is that there are very many connections to the database. Each connection has a thread stack and the memory for those stacks can add up to a considerable amount. Keeping this statistic reasonably low is important as the memory used here is unavailable for caching.

So now I am wondering whether or not the amount I am seeing here is unreasonable and if it is actually a problem, or if it's fine. The amounts can be seen in the image, but I will also explain them in text here, just in case.

My db size is about 12.5GB. Resident memory usage is at 11GB, mapped at 18GB and virtual at a whopping 118GB. The amount of connections to the db is about 50 (moving between 40 and 60), so that doesn't seem like the cause.

It might be worth noting that I see a lot of entries similar to this in `pmap` output:

```
0000013f9dfff000 521296K -----    [ anon ]
000001439e400000   1024K -----    [ anon ]
000001439e500000   1024K rw---    [ anon ]
000001439e600000   2048K -----    [ anon ]
000001537ce33000    820K -----    [ anon ]
000001537cf00000     20K rw---    [ anon ]
000001537cf05000      4K -----    [ anon ]
000001537cf06000    996K rwx--    [ anon ]
000001537cfff000      4K -----    [ anon ]
000001537d000000     20K rw---    [ anon ]
000001537d005000      4K -----    [ anon ]
000001537d006000    996K rwx--    [ anon ]
```

Especially the first entry of approximately .5GB seems excessive. I see it coming back very often, 159 times according to some grepping. So that would explain most of the amount that I am seeing. I don't know where these entries are coming from though.

I am using MongoDB v2.4.1 on CentOS 6.4 (64 bits).

[image: MMS screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I investigated and had some strong indications that the issue was related to using `rockmongo`. I launched a private support ticket with 10gen and they found that the issue was indeed `rockmongo` related. Apparently it uses a lot of `eval()` calls which spawn a server side V8 javascript engine requiring a lot of memory. I filed a bug-report with `rockmongo`.

Comment: Can you share the bug report link for reference?  Use of eval is evil (pardon the pun), so I wouldn't mind taking a look

Comment: The `rockmongo` issue can be found here: https://github.com/iwind/rockmongo/issues/28. The ticket with mongo is private, so I can't share that unfortunately. Unfortunately, the `rockmongo` ticket has little more info than what's in my answer. There has been no activity from their side and I have stopped using it (using `robomongo` now, since we changed our setup to allow VPN).